# Inherit base Dbcontext class

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5, dbcontext, ado.net-entity-data-model

I have a question about **inheriting** a custom `DbContext` class.

I have created a custom `DbContext` class called `BaseContext` in namespace 1 using C# Ado.net entity model generator as shown here:

```
namespace NS1
{
   public partial class BaseContext: DbContext
   {
        public BaseContext(): base("name=BaseContext")            
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }

        public virtual DbSet<PLAYERS> PLAYERS { get; set; }   
   }
}
```

And in the other namespace, I have created another context which uses the same database but its some other tables.

```
namespace NS2
{
   public partial class ExtensionContext: DbContext
   { 
       public ExtensionContext(): base("name=ExtensionContext")
       {
       }

       protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
       { 
         throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
       }

       public virtual DbSet<CRICKET_PLAYERS> CRICKET_PLAYERS { get; set; }      
   }
}
```

Now I am in a situation to use `PLAYERS` DbSet in the `ExtensionContext`. I have tried to inherit the `BaseContext` from `ExtensionContext` and pass the `ExtensionContext` connection string to the `BaseContext` constructor which in turn sends to the `DbContext`.

But during implementation I get an exception stating

> The PLAYERS name does not exist in the current ExtensionContext

Please give me some insight into the possibility of reusing the existing `DbSet` types in the extended context.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Runtime exception or the compile-time error?

Comment: I have solved the problem by simply omitting the creation of .edmx using ADO.Net Entity Model. Instead, I am writing my own POCOs and following the typical code first approach as desc. here http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/661053/Entity-Framework-Code-First-Map.